# How to add current logged in status to Users Schema in MongoDB using Passport and node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I’m quite new to backend development…

With using my API I would like to be able to display a list of users and also indicate if they are currently logged in. I got the basic authentification working using `passport` and `json web token` 
I’m **not** looking to get the current logged in user. 
I want to be able to retrieve a list of users and see if they are logged in or not.

Like this:

```
var users = Users.find({});
// console.log(users) output:
{
  name: 'foo'
  password: ...
  isLoggedIn: false
},
{
  name: 'bar'
  password: ...
  isLoggedIn: true
},
{
  name: 'baz'
  password: ...
  isLoggedIn: false
}
```

isLoggedIn would be set to `true` if the user is currently logged in and to `false`if not.

How can I do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like what you would like to do is update your MongoDB database based on login/logout events. To do this you could use something like [mongoose](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose) to work with your Node backend to easily access your database in MongoDB.

You can include mongoose after installing with `npm install mongoose` like so:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model('User');
```

Note that `User` corresponds to whatever schema you create for storing user information.

Assuming you have some sort of `router` object for handling requests, you could construct route handlers for `/logout` and `/login` and use your imported mongoose User model to retrieve and then modify a specific User object as such:

```
// whenever user goes to '/login' (you can have, say, your 'login' button make a request to this URL

router.get('/login', function(req,res) {
   // your authentication here; passport stores the currently authenticated user in req.user 
   var username = req.user.name; // here we assume the username is stored as 'name' as you have in your code but change this based on your schema
   User.findOne({name: username}, function(err, user, data) {
      if(err) res.send(err);
      user.isLoggedIn = true;
      user.save(function (err) {
         if (err) {
            console.log(err);
         } else {
            // redirect to some page here maybe
         }
      });
   });
});

// whenever user goes to '/logout' (you can have a logout button make a request to this URL

router.get('/logout', function(req,res) {
   // currently authenticated user is still in req.user
   var username = req.user.name;
   User.findOne({name: username}, function(err, user, data) {
      if(err) res.send(err);
      user.isLoggedIn = false;
      user.save(function (err) {
         if (err) {
            console.log(err);
         } else {
            // redirect to login/register page maybe
         }
      });
   });
});
```

So to summarize what this code would do:

- based on the url a user would go to, our route handler would fetch one correct, unique User object from our database based on the name (username)
- it would do so by accessing the username property of `req.user` which corresponds to the currently authenticated user with Passport, which, again will be different for all users
- update the field that we use to keep track of login status (`isLoggedIn`)
- and then save the changes, after which we are done updating the state to reflect whether the user is logged in or not, so we can now redirect to some other page or display other content

Finally then, you could retrieve a list of all users similarly to your code like so:

```
User.find({}, function(err, users, data) {
   // all users from your database are in `users`
   console.log(users);
});
```

**Edit for expired sessions:**

So, to track expired sessions, since you're using Passport, would in theory require functionality to signal with some sort of event / callback / message, etc. the moment the session is deemed invalid. Now that is tough to monitor and from my experience with Passport, stuff like that isn't implemented in all authentication strategies and might vary based on the strategy to be used by developers (think for instance if a browser window is closed, based on Passports authentication strategy, or just browser, it might destroy the cookie for the session right away and our server has no way of knowing about it). I do recommend checking out all the authentication strategies Passport offers in case there are some better ones [here](http://passportjs.org/features).

Now, if you would like to add functionality to track the users passive login/logout status with sessions yourself, you could use something related to cookies. Again, not necessarily one to use, but here's a couple handy Express modules: [cookie-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser) and [cookie-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-session).

Then, you could set and read cookies like this, using `cookie-parser`:

```
var express      = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
```

You would put this code somewhere right after the user is authenticated:

```
// cookies are stored here
console.log(req.cookies); 

// configure your cookie
var options = {
    expires: 1000 * 60 * 60, // expires after one hour
    httpOnly: true
}

// Set cookie
res.cookie('session', ('user-' + req.user.name), options);
```

And then, on the client side check if that cookie is valid continuously on some time interval, and if it expired `Date.now() > cookie.expires` then make a GET request to `/logout`, and there log out the user (currently still authenticated) by updating MongoDB and all.

However, since this would require making a mechanism to basically *simulate* an expired session, I would recommend using something analogous to a timeout, which would be much easier to implement. Just a note, this is sort of analogous to mechanisms on some pages you might have encountered where you get a pop-up saying 'You will be logged out due to inactivity'. In your `main.js` or whatever client-side script define a function to keep going on a time-out, unless the user does some action.

```
var inactivity = function () {
   var t;

   // user doing something on your page, so keep resetting time counter when events happen
   document.onmousemove = resetTimer;
   document.onkeypress = resetTimer;

   // this is a callback function that will get called once a time-out countdown is done
   function timeOut() {
      // make a request to '/logout' here and logout the current user (you still will have access to req.user from Passport)
      // also can redirect from back-end route handler to the login page for instance
   }

   // this gets called whenever an event happens, resetting the counter of sorts
   function resetTimer() {
       t = 0;
       t = setTimeout(timeOut, 1000 * 60 ) // set this to however long you should wait to log out your user time (in milliseconds)
   }
 };
```

So basically what this approach would let you do, is automatically invalidate sessions *yourself*, which means you would have much greater control over updating the state of your database and logging users out.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How to handle scenarios where the user do not actively log out? For example an expired session?

Comment: Sure, I've added some edits to the post outlining potential solutions / options, even though I don't think there's one correct way of handling this. Hope it's helpful.